# Vuex can't update component after mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to update a component after i pushed something new into my array. I create a post in createPost.vue and commit it into my store.js file where it store the object that i send into the state.

The problem i got is that i have too refresh the page to get the new data in the array.

createPost.vue:

```
<script>
import store from '../store'
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    methods:{
        postPostToDb(title,content){
            const postObj = {
                title:title,
                content:content,
            }
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/api/posts', postObj)
            .then((postObj)=>{
                this.$store.commit('ADD_POST', postObj);
            });
        },
    }, 
}
</script>
```

This is where i get all the data from store.js.

```
<script>
import store from '../store'

export default {
    computed:{
      items:function(){
        return store.state.posts;
      },
    },
    async created(){
      let data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/v1/api/posts');
      data = await data.json();
      this.$store.commit('INIT_POST', data);
  },
}
</script>
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      posts: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_POST(state,postObj){
        state.posts.push(postObj);
        alert(state.posts);
    },
    INIT_POST(state,postObj){
      postObj.forEach(element => {
        state.posts.push(element);
      });
    },
  },
  actions: {

  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution yet? I've got my mutations that sets loggedIn to false but app ignores it until I refresh the page. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mapGetters like this.

```
<script>
import store from '../store'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
    computed:{
        ...mapGetters({
            posts: 'getPosts'
        })
    },
    async created(){
      let data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/v1/api/posts');
      data = await data.json();
      this.$store.commit('INIT_POST', data);
  },
}
</script>
```

now the computed var "items" its accessible as "posts".

And in the Store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      posts: [],
  },
  getters: {
      getPosts(state) {
          return state.posts
      }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_POST(state,postObj){
        state.posts.push(postObj);
        alert(state.posts);
    },
    INIT_POST(state,postObj){
      postObj.forEach(element => {
        state.posts.push(element);
      });
    },
  },
  actions: {

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [Vue reactivity caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). You need to update `state.posts` object to make vuex reactive. Please try:

```
  ADD_POST(state,postObj){
      state.posts = state.posts.concat([postObj])
  },
```

Comment: Dosen't work, tried it but the array only get changed after i refreshed

Answer (score 0):

You are using Vuex incorrectly.

If you set it up right, the store should be available as `this.$store`, and the computed value should look like

```
computed:{
  items:function(){
    return this.$store.state.posts;
  },
},
```